# How to revert this thing in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I changed the theme of my Eclipse and now when hovering a method/anything the background of the container is black, and nothing cant be read about the method.

Check this :

[image]

Comment: Does in _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts_ changing the color _Basic > Information background color_ fix your issue? If not, please tell which Eclipse version and which theme do you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ***Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*** change the color ***Basic > Information background color***.